# How can I retrieve a really large data from firestore with a lot of collections and subcollections that need to be displayed separately?

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, dart

I am pretty new to flutter and firestore, but I got a project I need to make. The app I am making has profiles and each profile displays different data. For example an user has x amount of clients and each client has x amount of different type of information. That being said in my mind I have to have users as the base and for each client to make a lot of sub-collections. However as I’m pretty new to this I don’t exactly know how to implement that in the UI and code behind it. If somebody can point me in some direction, that would be great.

Comment: Read this docs https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#read-data

Answer (score 0):

Firestore allows you to paginate your data using cursors.

This is an example [From The Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#use_a_document_snapshot_to_define_the_query_cursor) using the web SDK but the principle is the same:

```js
import { collection, query, orderBy, startAfter, limit, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";  

// Query the first page of docs
const first = query(collection(db, "cities"), orderBy("population"), limit(25));
const documentSnapshots = await getDocs(first);

// Get the last visible document
const lastVisible = documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length-1];
console.log("last", lastVisible);

// Construct a new query starting at this document,
// get the next 25 cities.
const next = query(collection(db, "cities"),
    orderBy("population"),
    startAfter(lastVisible),
    limit(25));
```

In terms of sub collections, each doc you retrieve will have a reference property which can be used to create nested subcollection calls instead of writing a function with the fully built path string.